# Difference between ulimit -n and /proc/$PID/limits

Tags: limit

In Linux, there is open file limit. I can use `ulimit -n` to see open file limit, which is 1024 default. Then I also can see per process open file soft/hard limit by looking at /proc/$PID/limits. I see soft = 1024 and hard = 4096.

I am wondering what is the difference between these two output?

Also, do `setRlimit()` and `getRlimit()` apply to system-wide or per process?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`ulimit -n` sets the soft limit by default; you can add the `-H` option to view/set the hard limit.

For the most part, soft and hard limits behave like this:

1. root's processes (actually, any process with `CAP_SYS_RESOURCE`) may raise or lower any limit on any process.
2. any user's processes may lower any limit on other processes owned by that user.
3. any user's processes may raise the soft limit up to the hard limit on processes owned by that user.
4. If a process attempts to exceed its soft limit, the attempt will fail.

So, hard limits function as a cap on soft limits (except for root, who as normal can do anything).

There is an exception: A soft CPU limit sends a `SIGXCPU` signal. A process *may* choose to ignore that, or spend time doing cleanup, etc. Once the hard CPU limit is crossed, the kernel sends `SIGKILL`—which is not catchable, handleable, or ignorable. So in this case, the soft limit functions as a warning "you're out of CPU time—finish up and exit promptly, or else!" and the hard limit is the "or else."

Most are per-process, but a few (such as `RLIMIT_NPROC`) are per user. The [getrlimit(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/getrlimit.2.html) manual page specifies for each limit.

Comment: Another related question, why sometimes my shell has ulimit -n =1024 and another process fired from this shell has soft limit = 4096(reading from /proc/PID/limits)

Comment: @sdeLevelNegativeTwo Did you fire off the process before or after the `ulimit -n`? It doesn't affect processes already fired off, only the shell and future ones. Other than that, the process may be upping its soft limit to the hard limit. So you could use `ulimit -H -n` to stop it.